# Как в миграциях Laravel 5.6 создавать индексы для полей к PostgreSQL 10.1?

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6

Хочу в скрипте миграций добавить в таблицу поле с проверкой на уникальность. Пробую сделать это двумя способами, которые привожу ниже. Но ни один из них не создает в PostgreSQL нужный индекс для поля. Само поле создается, а индекс - нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Вариант 1

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('testtable', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string( 'testfield' )->unique();

        });
    }
```

Вариант 2

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('testtable', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string( 'testfield' );

            $table->unique( 'testfield', 'testfield_unique' );

        });
    }
```

Comment: Попробуй во втором варианте указать список полей в массиве

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотреть нужно не Indexes, а Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
php composer require doctrine/dbal
```

2)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class YouMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('testtable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('testfield')->unique()->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
    }
}
```